# Curl return html code when ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I using curl to send request to another page and return value to ajax, i have prevented curl redirect to another and just return value to ajax but final result i receive from ajax have contain html code, my code:

php:

```
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://abc.com');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                echo 'my value';
```

ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://pagephp.com",
                data: data,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
           });
```

alert will show: `<html>...</html> my value`

help me

Comment: What are you expecting to get back? A JSON object or some Javascript code? You might need to set the `dataType` option in your ajax call to whatever you're expecting. Check the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Comment: i need to get a string to ajax, not json

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true/1 then your return value from curl_exec will be the actual result from your successful operation. In other words it will not return `TRUE` on success. Although it will return `FALSE` on failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

You should enable the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option for redirects but this would be a problem if your server in in safe_mode and/or open_basedir in effect which can cause issues with curl as well.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://abc.com');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            echo json_encode('my value');
```

JQUERY

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://pagephp.com",
                data: data,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
           });
```

Comment: oh, i don't want get value from abc.com. it is page to send parameter and i echo any value to ajax

Comment: If you don't need return values from abc.com what do you need ?

Comment: yes, i will send parameters to abc and don't get anything from it, then i send a message to ajax

Comment: what type of massage ? success massage ?

Comment: send a string to ajax, nothing else and my problem is a string contain html code